# Simplest way to define a component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am not familiar with Typescript. I am just curious about the way to define React functional-based component by using Typescript without declaring its function name just like the following Javascript code.

```
import react from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'

export default () => {
    return (
      <View/>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to @ZohirSalak. Could you check the screenshot?

Comment: Typescript does not support XML inside of it, neither does JS. It's JSX that supports that syntax, and respectively your file has to be `tsx`.

Comment: I think my question is clear and simple. The above code is full of a js file, prefect running. Just I am curious if there is anything alternative way in Typescript. Must I define const variable and export it? I did find nothing while googling.